# Passing data from React component to Laravel controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, laravel-blade

I a laravel project using React js for the font-end , i would like to pass some data rendered by a React component to my controller. In a blade template i have a form , and within that form , i'm displaying a "select" element using React js. How to pass the value in the select element via the Request(Request $request) variable to the controller?
Here is my form in the blade template:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
        @csrf

    <div id="example" data={{ $currencies }}></div>

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

And there is the component:

```
class Example extends Component {
    render() {
                return(
            <div>
          <select>
            <option></option>
            <option>Currency</option>
            <option>Reputation</option>
          </select>

        </div>
            );

            }
  }

export default Example;

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
     var data = document.getElementById('example').getAttribute('data');
    ReactDOM.render(<Example data={data}/>, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

Comment: Add a name property to the select, url to the form action attribute and submit the form.

Comment: worked! thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can simply send or pass the data to laravel route or controller directly . You can use `fetch()` method or [`axios()`](https://github.com/axios/axios) to send the data in post method to the url and catch that in the respective controller. As react component or can say react is only the view of the MVC that there is no way(may be in my knowledge) to pass the data to server side with a api request like fetch() n all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by using react-select component to load data into the select element like below.

```
<Select
  options={JSON.parse(data)}
/>
```

Data must be in JSON format to display in react-select component. Example data is as follows,

```
[
  {
    "value": "inr",
    "label": "Indian Rupees"
  },
  {
    "value": "usd",
    "label": "United States Dollars"
  },
  {
    "value": "aud",
    "label": "Australian Dollars"
  }
]
```

You can also use simple select element and loop through data to add options into the select element.